# Retrieve size of Ethereum state on a local Go-Ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum, state, blockchain-size

I have a local go-ethereum node and I would like to measure the size of its state on disk. The chain DB is under a `.ethereum` directory but measuring the size of this dir would also include space used by all the blocks and transactions.

I'm looking for the space required by state only. Does anyone knows how to retrieve this info?

Thanks